# creates the file doesnt write java

Tags: java, file-io, writefile

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter filename");
        Filename=in.next();
        PrintWriter outputFile  =new PrintWriter(Filename);
        outputFile.println();
        outputFile.close();
        getInput();
        display();

    }

    public static void display() throws FileNotFoundException{
        for (int i = 0; i < genders.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(ages[i]+";"+genders[i]+";"+emails[i]+";"+salaries[i]);
    }}


    public static void getInput(){

        System.out.print("How many users do you wish to enter: ");
        int num = in.nextInt();
        ages= new int[num];
        genders = new String[num];
        emails = new String[num];
        salaries = new double[num];

        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            System.out.print("Please enter your age for person "+(i+1)+": ");
            ages[i] = in.nextInt();
            while (ages[i]<20 ||ages[i]>30){
                System.out.println("invalid age please re enter again");
                ages[i] = in.nextInt();}
            in.nextLine();
```

hey guys i am trying to write the contents of user input into a file. my problem is it creates the file but doesnt write to it. i have tried various methods but doesnt work any help?

Comment: Frankly, your code is a bit messy, but I'm still trying to look at your code. Don't worry, you're not abandoned.

Comment: Duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18070629/how-to-read-from-users-input-in-java-and-write-it-to-a-file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18070629/how-to-read-from-users-input-in-java-and-write-it-to-a-file)

Comment: Which part of the code is supposed to write user input to the file? You only write a single blank line to the file, all other output is to the console.

Comment: @Andreas so whats the correct way to write all the contents of the user input to the file?sorry i'm confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is answered here:  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18070629/how-to-read-from-users-input-in-jav‌​a-and-write-it-to-a-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18070629/how-to-read-from-users-input-in-jav%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Ba-and-write-it-to-a-file)

But to summarise: You are simply creating a file named after the user's input. You need to actually write that information to the file:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainClass {
    private static String   fileName;
    private static String[] genders, emails;
    private static double salaries[];
    private static int    userCount;
    private static int[]  ages;
    private static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        System.out.println("enter filename");
        fileName = in.nextLine();
        File myFile = new File(fileName);
        getInput();
        display();
        FileWriter fWriter = null;
        BufferedWriter writer = null;
        try {
            fWriter = new FileWriter(myFile);
            writer = new BufferedWriter(fWriter);
            writer.write(display().toString());
            writer.newLine();
            writer.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error!");
        }
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> display() throws FileNotFoundException {
        ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < genders.length; i++) {

            data.add(ages[i] + ";" + genders[i] + ";" + emails[i] +
                     ";" + salaries[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < genders.length; i++) {

            System.out.println(ages[i] + ";" + genders[i] + ";" + emails[i] +
                               ";" + salaries[i]);
        }
        return data;
    }

    private static void getInput() {
        System.out.print("How many users do you wish to enter: ");
        int userCount = in.nextInt();
        ages = new int[userCount];
        genders = new String[userCount];
        emails = new String[userCount];
        salaries = new double[userCount];

        for (int i = 0; i < userCount; i++) {
            System.out.print("Please enter your age for person " + (i + 1) +
                             ": ");
            ages[i] = in.nextInt();
            while (ages[i] < 20 || ages[i] > 30) {
                System.out.println("invalid age please re enter again");
                ages[i] = in.nextInt();
            }
            in.nextLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried this it doesnt work. it still doesnt print anything to the text file

Comment: @user3607224, edited to include a full working example. All you should have to do at this point is add the appropriate pieces to get the genders, emails, and salaries to `getInput()`

Answer (score 2):

```
    Filename=in.next();
    PrintWriter outputFile  =new PrintWriter(Filename);
    outputFile.println();
```

I think you are creating the file with the name of user input, and prints an empty line to it